# CS50 finance. History - Added Column for TYPE of Transaction Buy or Sell in Database not showing up in html page

Tags: html, sql, cs50

I added a TYPE column which states whether or not the transaction in question was a sell or a buy.  When I load the history.html page and try to include it, the column is blank; however, when I check the database it is not and it says whether it was a buy or sell.  I did add the TYPE column after the database was created and for this reason I could not select not null as an option; but, the buy and sell functions are inserting the type data correctly.  Any suggestions as to how to get this data to present itself on the history page.

```
@app.route("/history")
@login_required
def history():
"""Show history of transactions"""
columns = db.execute("""SELECT symbol, shares, price, stock_total, time, type
                     FROM transactions
                     WHERE users_id = :users_id
                  """, users_id=session["user_id"])

for column in columns:
    name = lookup(column["symbol"])["name"]
    column.update({ "name": name })

return render_template("history.html", columns=columns)
```

History.html page

```
{% block main %}
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Symbol</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Shares</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Type</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
         {% for column in columns %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ column.symbol }}</td>
            <td>{{ column.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ column.shares }}</td>
            <td>{{ column.price | usd }}</td>
            <td>{{ column.stock_total | usd }}</td>
            <td>{{ column.time }}</td>
            <td>{{ column.type }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>

    </tfoot>
 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: There will be additional service layer in between database and presentation layer(html).

Comment: Could you show the `history.html` code?